# Writing to a file multiple times with Bash

Tags: bash, echo

I am creating a bash script to automate some commands and I am having some trouble writing my error checking to the same file.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch ErrorLog.txt

bro-cut service < conn.log | sort | uniq -c > ProtocolHierarchy.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "OK Protocol Hierarchy Created\n" > ErrorLog.txt
else
    echo -e "FAILED Creating Protocol Hierarchy\n" > ErrorLog.txt
fi

bro-cut id.orig_h < dns.log | sort | uniq -c > AllIPAddresses.txt

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "OK Created all IP Addresses\n" > ErrorLog.txt
else
    echo -e "FAILED Creating all IP Addresses\n" > ErrorLog.txt
fi
```

The goal being to have a file I can open and see that all the commands worked or failed, currently the file looks like this

```
-e OK Created all IP Addresses
```

When I would like it to look like this

```
OK Protocol Hierarchy Created
OK Created all IP Addresses
```

I am really new to bash scripting so any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `echo -e` -- it's not POSIX-defined, and thus not guaranteed to behave identically across all shells (which is why you're seeing a shell print `-e` on output -- that's actually proper, standards-compliant behavior). Use `printf '%b\n' "something"` instead of `echo -e "something"`, as described in the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: Hmm. Since you have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, I wonder if your script is being run with `sh yourscript`? That overrides the shebang, and forces `sh` to be used instead of `bash`; that would explain why you're seeing `-e` printed, instead of bash's normal noncompliant behavior.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open it once, and write to that file descriptor multiple times.

```
# Open (creating or truncating) the output file (only once!)
exec 3>ErrorLog.txt

# Write a line to that already-open file
echo "something" >&3

# Write a second line to that already-open file
echo "something else" >&3

# Optional: close the output file (can also be implicit when the script exits)
exec 3>&-
```

The other common idiom is to open in append mode using `>>`, but doing that once per line is considerably less efficient.

```
# Open ErrorLog.txt, truncating if it exist, write one line, and close it
echo "something" >ErrorLog.txt

# Reopen ErrorLog.txt, write an additional line to the end, and close it again
echo "something else" >>ErrorLog.txt
```

---

Putting this practice to work in your script (and making some other best-practice improvements) looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# not related to file output, but to making sure we detect errors
# only works correctly if run with bash, not sh!
set -o pipefail ## set exit status based on whole pipeline, not just last command

# picking 3, since FD numbers 0-2 are reserved for stdin/stdout/stderr
exec 3>ErrorLog.txt

if bro-cut service <conn.log | sort | uniq -c >ProtocolHierarchy.txt; then
    echo "OK Protocol Hierarchy Created" >&3
else
    echo "FAILED Creating Protocol Hierarchy" >&3
fi

if bro-cut id.orig_h <dns.log | sort | uniq -c >AllIPAddresses.txt; then
    echo "OK Created all IP Addresses" >&3
else
    echo "FAILED Creating all IP Addresses" >&3
fi
```

Comment: This worked perfect and solved my problem, thank you so much! I will accept the answer in a few minutes when it opens

Comment: Note that the original code (and this answer too, without the bash-only `set -o pipefail` line -- so be sure not to run this with `sh`!) has the `if`s branch on the exit status of `uniq`, ignoring a failure from `bro-cut` or `sort`.

Comment: +1 -- just learned a new thing: `exec 3>ErrorLog.txt` then `echo "something" >&3` . I had never seen that anywhere

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have been running the command like this: sh script.sh -- is this wrong/ wouldn't work across various Unix systems?

Comment: @firetiger443, `sh script.sh` runs the script with `sh` as interpreter, **not** `bash`, whereas starting your script with `#!/bin/bash` indicates that it's meant to be run with `bash`, not `sh`. Pick one or the other, and use it consistently -- but if you want features such as `set -o pipefail` which aren't part of the POSIX sh specification to be consistently available then you need to use bash.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you! I got the script to work - I added some more commands I needed, just to verify, to run this I currently use chmod +x file_name then ./file_name -- is this correct?

Comment: Yup, that's spot on.