# bash, using here document, how can I read multiple lines of user input, stop on blank line

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

Is there a way that I can make a heredoc in a script interactive as if I am at the prompt?

This is over ssh from linux to an ssh server runing on android connecting through mosh.

I'm making a set of a few small scripts to allow me to reasonably sms over ssh on my android from my laptop using bash under the app termux.

While testing the send command at the prompt all works well:

```
termux-sms-send -n "$(tail -n1 number | tr -d ' ')" << ''
```

However, when inside a script this no longer works. This is the result:

```
./main.sh: line 34: warning: here-document at line 33 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `')
./main.sh: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I could of course do it another way but it's so neat and simple with the heredoc method and it's something I haven't really used before in bash and I am unsure how to get the read command to work nicely with multi line input in such a graceful way as this.

__

Edit Addition:

In case anyone is interested and for context this is the script:

```
searchTxt=""
contacts="$(termux-contact-list | jq -r '.[].name')"

clear 

while :; do
   echo -ne "\nEnter searchterm: $searchTxt"
   read -rsn1 ret; clear

   if [ ${#ret} -eq 0 ]; then
      if [ $(wc -l <<< "$choice") -gt 1 ]; then
         echo -en "type enough characters to narrow down selecton until only 1 remains\n\n"
      else
         echo "choice = $choice"
         number="$(termux-contact-list | jq -r ".[] | select(.name==\"$choice\") | .number")"
         echo "using number: $number"
         echo "$choice" > number
         echo "$number" >> number
         break
      fi
   fi

   searchTxt+=$ret
   choice=$(grep -i "$searchTxt" <<< "$contacts")
   echo "$choice"
done

while :; do
   clear 
   echo "Type message to send, enter a blank line to send message"
   echo -n "message: "

   termux-sms-send -n "$(tail -n1 number | tr -d ' ')" << ''
done
```

Comment: Did you mean to use an empty here *string* instead of a here document? `termux-sms-send ... <<< ''`

Comment: If I understand correctly (and you're feeding the script text to the remote interpreter's stdin via a heredoc over SSH), SSH is really a critical part of this question -- having it only mentioned in the prose but its use not shown in an example is underplaying it. And if I *don't* understand correctly, perhaps there's some clarification to be done.

Comment: Or do you simply want to have `termux-sms-send` inherit its standard input from the script, in which case you don't need to do anything?

Comment: BTW, you're mixing code and data when you use `jq -r "...\"$choice\"..."`; that's prone to injection issues, which could turn into security bugs if future versions of `jq` add file I/O extensions or the ability to execute external programs. Instead, use `jq --arg choice "$choice" '...$choice...'`, where `$choice` is passed as a `jq` variable separate from the code.

Comment: I'm looking to have it prompt for text when it reaches that command. So that I can type a message, which may have multiple lines and then have that typed message sent to the termux-sms-send command.  I was unaware ssh was an important part to mention, I'll add that now.

Comment: ...so, if you **weren't** using ssh, you could `read </dev/tty` to get content direct from the user even with stdin directed from a file/heredoc/etc. Whether you can do that in the presence of SSH depends on details not yet given (but hopefully there when you're done editing).

Comment: (and btw, `<< ''` isn't generally accepted syntax. What's it expected to do? Are you sure you didn't typo `<<< ''`? And if that *is* what you wanted, I'd consider `</dev/null` instead, which is both more efficient and more portable)

Comment: (...speaking of "more efficient", `echo foo > number; echo bar >> number` opens the `number` file twice; there's no good reason to do that: `{ echo foo; echo bar; } >number` will open `number` only once; also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947571/writing-to-a-file-multiple-times-with-bash/43947590#43947590).

Comment: Yes the use of << '' is deliberate. It makes the command finish reading when it reaches a blank line. It was a convenience thing to save from typing EOF. So when im finished my text. I simply hit enter twice. I definitely don't mean <<< as that doesn't prompt even at the command line.

Comment: (and `echo -e` and `echo -n` are both better avoided: any shell that doesn't print `-e` when given `echo -e` is actually defying [black-letter POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); and while bash does in fact contain such a violation *by default*, both compile-time and runtime configuration that eliminate it are available).

Comment: Lots of good feedback thanks, I especially like the efficiency one to open a file only once. As for portability and compatibility with other things for now this is personal use only on just my phone.

Comment: Gotcha. Cute. That said, I'm not aware of any documentation guaranteeing that a heredoc with an empty string as its sigil will continue to work in the future -- and if it's not documented, it can go away without notice. It's also not recognized by http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed idiom is looking for a bare newline *in the code* (since the code is from where the heredoc is being read), as opposed to a bare newline *in stdin*.

That works at an interactive prompt, where your code is coming from stdin -- but the reason it doesn't work *from a script* should be obvious.

The following loop is explicit about looking in the input stream:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line ]] || break
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done | termux-sms-send -n "$(tail -n1 number | tr -d ' ')"
```

Comment: This is a more sane solution. After reading your comments about portability and future proofing the longer but more robust method does seem best. Thank you very much for all the tips. I didn't expect to learn so much from this question, its much appreciated =)

Comment: Note that some time around Q1 2019, Google started cracking down on app security policy. As a result, the Termux project was forced to remove SMS functionality in order to keep the app in the Play Store. However, installing Termux from the F-Droid package manager apparently still has SMS functionality.